# Simple Linear Regression Question Confusion

Tags: regression, linear

[image]

By using [this site](https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/regression/default.aspx) I found the two linear regression models that the question asked.

The equations came out to be:
$$US=60.495+18.550x$$
$$China =-2.08+18.296x$$

A follow-up question asked me to find "What year will china take over the US in terms of internet users"? Therefore I equated the two equations and got $x \approx -246$.

Since I 'indexed' $1998$ as $0$ and $2000$ as $2$ and so on. The answer is $1998 - 246 = 1752$

The year 1752 and internet does not really make a lot of sense. I totally get why this answer results from the linear models mentioned above. However, I am confused and I think I could be missing something that is resulting in a wrong answer.

I see how some curves will fit here nicely but [The Question](https://media.cheggcdn.com/study/1d6/1d627bd8-4cbc-4873-ac7b-0aad42c32f78/image.png) specifically asks for linear regression models.

Comment: Just by comparing your equations to the lines in the chart it seems clear that they are swapped (the "USA equation" represents the "China line" and the "China equation" represents the "USA line")

Comment: @AdriàLuz But wouldn't the answer $x$ be the same regardless?

Comment: Sorry, I've confused myself with the chart legend. Your equations are fine!

Comment: Are you sure the equations are correct? I'm getting a negative number:
$$
60.495 + 18.55x=-2.08+18.296x\\62.575=-0.254x\\x=-\frac{62.575}{0.254}\approx-246
$$

Comment: @AdriàLuz Thanks for the reply. Yes, the question says "x years from 1998" so basically I indexed the year 1998 as 0 and 2000 as 2. And, your right, x is $-246$ as in 246 years behind 1998, I should fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think those equations are wrong. From equating them I get $x\approx-246$.

I've copied the data from the chart into R:

```r
df <- tibble(
  year = seq(1998, 2008, by = 2),
  usa = c(44.23, 83.05, 169.57, 190.43, 206.49, 225.69),
  china = c(2.1, 22.54, 59.09, 94.94, 138.33, 200.5)
)
```

And fitted the two regression models:

```r
usa_m <- lm(usa ~ year, data = df)
china_m <- lm(china ~ year, data = df)
```

I get the following equations:
$$
\operatorname{USA}=-37001.834+18.550\operatorname{year}\\
\operatorname{China}=-39264.688+19.646\operatorname{year}
$$

If you equate these:
$$
-37001.834+18.550\operatorname{year}=-39264.688+19.646\operatorname{year}\\
-1.096\operatorname{year}=-2262.854\\
\operatorname{year}=\frac{2262.854}{1.096}\approx2065
$$

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! Thank you, I think I see what went wrong with whatever I did. My China equation is wrong, I put in 21 instead of 2.1.